# Django Unable to access LiveServerTestCase (code 500)

Tags: python, django, selenium

I was following Django docs, but am still having problem with this example - I get `500 Internal server error` when accesing the live server with Selenium.

My code:

```
import os

try:
    browser_driver = os.environ['BROWSER_DRIVER']
except KeyError:
    raise ValueError("BROWSER_DRIVER env variable not specified. \nPlease specify path to your "
                     "browsers driver, more information: "
                     "https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers")

os.environ["PATH"] += browser_driver

from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver


class TestMostCommonUserActions(LiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.selenium = webdriver.Chrome()
        cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(10)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test_slicing_is_possible_after_adding_and_subtracting_custom_slicing_info(self):
        # Here is the problem
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/'))
        pass
```

When I run my server on localhost and try to access with selenium localhost on port 8000, it works. But shouldn't be the whole point of LiveServerTestCase to not to have the real django server?

Answer (score -1):

your home page view is probably the problem. template_name might be incorrect.

I have a similar problem, was able to access but the LiverServerTestCase/live_server_url couldn't load my context variable to display on the page...it seems like this is a django 3 problem...not many people got this problem yet